# How do I rank a list of features that I have picked out in the given data and rank the features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am currently doing ML on house prediction dataset. > [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OKbzSwWVIgnJtltwvqzgxg8uGVD-mGx_)

How do I select 10 best features in my dataset for aiding in building a model for predicting SalePrice and how to rank the 10 features ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a feature ranking algorithm like "ReliefF"or use a dimensionality reduction technique like PCA, which will transform all of your features into your desired number of features.

This is also a good link for learning more about feature selection:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/

You might also need to convert strings to numbers in features where the values are alphanumeric in nature.